# Select value doesn't update on change in React

Tags: reactjs, select, onchange

When I choose option in select, in placeholder or label it doesn't update to chosen value. I have no more ideas how to fix it :(

I have two components. First:

```
class CreateProfile extends Component {
  state = {
    position: "",
  };

  addPosition = e => {
    const positionChosen = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
      position: positionChosen
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { position } = this.state;

  return(
   <AssignPosition
    addPosition={this.addPosition}
    position={position}
   />
 )
}
}
```

And in second file a have:

```
class AssignPosition extends Component {
  render() {
    const { addPosition, position } = this.props

  return(
    <select
       name="select"
       onChange={addPosition}
       value={position}
    >
       <option value="null">Choose position</option>
       <option value="position1">position1</option>
       <option value="position2">position2</option>
       <option value="position3">position3</option>
    </select>
  )
 }
}
```

When I select a position, as a label there's still "Choose position" not a value, that I have chosen. I don't want to paste too much code here, but in fact, it is multi step form. In AssignPosition I choose position and then click "next" to summary. And what's important, when I click "next" and then I click "back" in select label there is a correct value so it gets updated but somehow too late...

Any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if you need more code.

Edit: I found a problem. 
In AssignPosition I have also ShouldComponentUpdate function.

```
 shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.addTest === nextProps.addTest) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

I need it, because on the same component I use MaterialTable and without this function, I had a problem described here: https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/469
When I delete ShouldComponentUpdate, select works properly, but selection in MaterialTable doesn't :/ Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-cray-1y6o1?file=/src/App.js) of your component. I can see that the `onChange`  is working properly. Anything I am missing here?

Comment: Yeah, it should work like in this sandbox but it doesn't in my app :( I don't know where to look for if this part of code is correct. As I told, it's multi step form. Maybe something it's not ok with passing state between components?

Comment: The problem is ShouldComponentUpdate function but I still don't know how to fix it... I updated my question.

Comment: can you create a sample with material table config you using. because as per the sample code provided, it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly - for some reason you use shouldComponentUpdate, so you should check if position in props is changed. Condition in shouldComponentUpdate should contain this.props.position === nextProps.position check.

Comment: As we discussed it further on facebook group you need condition like 
`if (this.props.addTest !== nextProps.addTest || this.props.position !== nextProps.position) {
return true;
} else {
return false;
}`
but I agree with Akhil - it would be easier if you share code.

Comment: I added MaterialTable code to sandbox provided earlier by Ajin Kabeer https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-khayyam-2xt3t?file=/src/App.js but you have already solved it :)